# androidのエミュレータが起動しない

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, flutter, dart

runボタンを押してandroidのエミュレータを起動させようとしたんですが、下記のようなエラーが発生して動きません。

エラー文
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下の投稿を参考にkotlinのバージョンを上げたんですが、だめでした。

[Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. (Android Studio) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919127/your-project-requires-a-newer-version-of-the-kotlin-gradle-plugin-android-stud)

修正したコード
/Users/fujitayuusaku/Private/sample/flutter_app/my_first_app/android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0' // Change here
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。解決しましたか？このサイトを参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか？
https://minpro.net/flutter-2-10-your-project-requires-a-newer-version-of-the-kotlin-gradle-plugin

Comment: できればURLだけでなく、解決策の概要だけでも解るような記述を追加して下さい。参考: [良い回答を書くには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) 「リンクの文脈を提示する」「外部リソースにアクセスできない場合やリンク先が永久的にオフラインになってしまう場合に備えて、重要なリンク先の最も関連性が高い部分を必ず引用してください」